# Mobile JSF how to start in Netbeans?

Tags: jsf, mobile, jsf-2, netbeans

I would like to write a simple, hello world page in JSF as well as for mobiles and ordinary web pages. Found this: http://mobiforge.com/book/mobile-jsf but seems to be outdated. I cant even download the plugin which is mentioned there (download is unavailable, 404).

I searched Internet and it seems that theres no simple step by step tutorial for writing mobile JSF pages. Any ideas where and how can I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it can help you to use a mobile component framework like [PrimeFaces Mobile](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/index.jsf) or [IceMobile](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEmobile/overview.jsf).

There are some tutorials which describe how to build mobile websites with JSF and PrimeFaces Mobile:

- [Create Mobile Websites using Java Server Faces and PrimeFaces Mobile](http://www.hascode.com/2012/01/create-mobile-websites-using-java-server-faces-and-primefaces-mobile/)
- [Primefaces Mobile - Weather App Example](http://armelnene.blogspot.de/2012/04/primefaces-mobile-weather-app-example.html)
- [PrimeFaces tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/primefaces/primefaces-tutorial)
- [PrimeFaces Mobile User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html)

Here are some tutorials about IceMobile:

- [ICEmobile Tutorials & Samples](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEmobile/tutorials.jsf)
- [Just add mobility: JSF and JSP with ICEmobile](http://jaxenter.com/just-add-mobility-jsf-and-jsp-with-icemobile-47199.html)

If you don't want to use a mobile JSF component framework you can search the web for the tutorials about combining mobile JavaScript frameworks like [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) with JSF.